# button width 100% if have only one post

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.8

I´m traying to create one button that it has width 100% in blade if only have only one post in blog.

i explaning better. i´m doing a blog. When open post i can see my post and two button (previous and next) if i´m in last post i want that previous button has withd 100% and i´m in first post the same. But if i´m in the second post, i need show prev and next at 50%.

in my controller i have this:

```
public function show($url)
    {
        $post = Blog::where('url', '=', $url)->first();

        $next = Blog::where('id', '>', $post->id)->min('id');
        $previous = Blog::where('id', '<', $post->id)->max('id');

        $nextPost = Blog::where('id', '=', $next)->first();
        $previousPost = Blog::where('id', '=', $previous)->first();

        //$popularPost = Blog::where('visualization', '>=', 5)->get();
        $categories = BlogCategory::all();

        //insert time when show post
        $this->visualizationRepository->countVisualization($post->id, 'Model\Blog', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

        return view('web.singleBlog')
            ->with('post', $post)
            ->with('popular', [])
            ->with('next', $nextPost)
            ->with('previous', $previousPost)
            ->with('categories', $categories);
    }
```

and in my view i have this:

```
<div class="post-nav-wrap fl-wrap">
      @if($previous != null)
        <a class="post-nav post-nav-prev" href="{{ url('blog/'.$previous->name)}}"><span class="post-nav-img"><img src="{{$previous->media[0]->url}}" alt=""></span><span class="post-nav-text"><strong></strong>{{trans('web.single_blog_previous_post')}}<br>{{$previous->name}}</span></a> 
      @endif
      @if($next != null)
        <a class="post-nav post-nav-next" href="{{ url('blog/'.$next->name)}}"><span class="post-nav-img"><img src="{{$next->media[0]->url}}" alt=""></span><span class="post-nav-text"><strong>{{trans('web.single_blog_next_post')}}</strong><br>{{$next->name}}</span></a>
         
       @endif
</div>
```

how i would can to do this? `next` and `previous` returned an object amd i can´t to do if check if it´s `>=1`

**update**

```
@if( $previous != null ) 
   @if( $next != null ) 
     <a class="post-nav post-nav-prev half" style="width: 100%;" href="{{ url('blog/'.$previous->name)}}"><span class="post-nav-img"><img src="{{$previous->media[0]->url}}" alt=""></span><span class="post-nav-text"><strong></strong>{{trans('web.single_blog_previous_post')}}<br>{{$previous->name}}</span></a> 
     <a class="post-nav post-nav-next half" style="width: 100%;" href="{{ url('blog/'.$next->name)}}"><span class="post-nav-img"><img src="{{$next->media[0]->url}}" alt=""></span><span class="post-nav-text"><strong>{{trans('web.single_blog_next_post')}}</strong><br>{{$next->name}}</span></a>
     @else
       <a class="post-nav post-nav-prev fullwidth " style="width: 100%;" href="{{ url('blog/'.$previous->name)}}"><span class="post-nav-img"><img src="{{$previous->media[0]->url}}" alt=""></span><span class="post-nav-text"><strong></strong>{{trans('web.single_blog_previous_post')}}<br>{{$previous->name}}</span></a> 
        @endif
     @else
      <a class="post-nav post-nav-next fullwidth" style="width: 100%;" href="{{ url('blog/'.$next->name)}}"><span class="post-nav-img"><img src="{{$next->media[0]->url}}" alt=""></span><span class="post-nav-text"><strong>{{trans('web.single_blog_next_post')}}</strong><br>{{$next->name}}</span></a>
@endif
```

**update 2**

```
<div class="post-nav-wrap fl-wrap">
     @if($previous != null)
     <a class="{{ $next !=  null ? 'half post-nav post-nav-prev' : 'full post-nav post-nav-prev' }}" href="{{ url('blog/'.$previous->name)}}"><span class="post-nav-img"><img src="{{$previous->media[0]->url}}" alt=""></span><span class="post-nav-text"><strong></strong>{{trans('web.single_blog_previous_post')}}<br>{{$previous->name}}</span></a> 
      @endif
      @if($next != null)
        <a class="{{ $next !=  null ? 'half post-nav post-nav-next' : 'full post-nav post-nav-next' }}" href="{{ url('blog/'.$next->name)}}"><span class="post-nav-img"><img src="{{$next->media[0]->url}}" alt=""></span><span class="post-nav-text"><strong>{{trans('web.single_blog_next_post')}}</strong><br>{{$next->name}}</span></a>
       @endif
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that if $next and $previous are object, if they are null it means that the current post is the last | first.

At this point, create a class if you're not using a css library :

```
.half { width: 50%; }
.fullwidth { width: 100%; }
```

Then you need to control if the current post is the first or the last :

```
@if( $previous != null ) 
    @if( $next != null ) 
        <!-- HERE YOUR PREVIOUS BTN WITH HALF CLASS -->
        <!-- HERE YOUR NEXT BTN WITH HALF CLASS -->
    @else
        <!-- HERE YOUR PREVIOUS BTN WITH FULL CLASS -->
    @endif
@else
    <!-- HERE YOUR NEXT BTN WITH FULL CLASS -->
@endif
```

Hope this could resolve your issue.

Comment: There is no need to add an if else condition here and duplicate the HTML tag. OP can just use the conditional operator in the tag. Eg: `<button class="{{ $next !=  null ? 'half' : 'full' }}">`

Comment: I expose only 'the logic' to solve his issue, obv is unnecessary duplicate tags.

Comment: @Emanuele thanks for your response, but when only have one post it´s correct, but if i enter in next post that i can show previous and next buton previous and next show to 100% and i don´t want this i want 50%

Comment: @thebrownkid i don´t know very weel to do that you said

Comment: @thebrownkid when i show next post that i can show previous an next button, i show two button at 100%

Comment: @daviserraalonso It is because you have style attribute added to the tag which is overriding the class and making it 100%. Remove the style attribute as your new set of classes will do the size change.

Also you can check this post to see how to use conditional operators -> [Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23382907/laravel-blade-add-a-class-if-a-condition-is-met)

Comment: @thebrownkid thanks for your response again, butn now i can´t show my button at 100%.. i think that i´m doin well my condition. I updated my question in updated 2. Again thanks for help

Comment: @daviserraalonso Just to double-check, did you add the css classes mentioned above to your stylesheet?
P.S. I'll suggest you to make use of the css library you are using in your project once you got it working.

Comment: @thebrownkid yes i add styles in my css stylesheet...

Comment: @daviserraalonso Probably an issue with the logic then. On a side note, you can inspect and check if the classes are being added properly or not and also whether your style changes are not being overridden by something else.

Comment: @thebrownkid always add half class to the component and i add !important in my css style