# how i can change the background color of the datatable based on the result

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatables

hi i am using Datatable in laravel

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
    $('#example thead tr')
        .clone(true)
        .addClass('filters')
        .appendTo('#example thead');

    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        orderCellsTop: true,
        fixedHeader: true,
        initComplete: function () {
            var api = this.api();

            // For each column
            api
                .columns()
                .eq(0)
                .each(function (colIdx) {
                    // Set the header cell to contain the input element
                    var cell = $('.filters th').eq(
                        $(api.column(colIdx).header()).index()
                    );
                    var title = $(cell).text();
                    $(cell).html('<input type="text" placeholder="' + title + '" />');

                    // On every keypress in this input
                    $(
                        'input',
                        $('.filters th').eq($(api.column(colIdx).header()).index())
                    )
                        .off('keyup change')
                        .on('keyup change', function (e) {
                            e.stopPropagation();

                            // Get the search value
                            $(this).attr('title', $(this).val());
                            var regexr = '({search})'; //$(this).parents('th').find('select').val();

                            var cursorPosition = this.selectionStart;
                            // Search the column for that value
                            api
                                .column(colIdx)
                                .search(
                                    this.value != ''
                                        ? regexr.replace('{search}', '(((' + this.value + ')))')
                                        : '',
                                    this.value != '',
                                    this.value == ''
                                )
                                .draw();

                            $(this)
                                .focus()[0]
                                .setSelectionRange(cursorPosition, cursorPosition);
                        });
                });
        },
    });

});
```

it is working fine but i want to change the background field of the data such as

```
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:10px;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Code</th>
                    <th>Employee</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Arrival time </th>
                    <th>Departure Time</th>
                    <th>Total</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach($attandance as $attandances)
                <tr>

                    <td>{{$attandances->code}}</td>
                    <td>{{$attandances->employee}}</td>
                    <td>{{$attandances->date}}</td>
                    <td>{{$attandances->start_time}}</td>
                    <td>{{$attandances->end_time}}</td>
                    <td>{{$attandances->total_hours}}</td>

                </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>


        </table>
```

i want to change the background color of the table such as if the total hours are less than the 9 hours the background color of that field should change to red ..or if there is any better way i can use datatables i am new to programming and doesn't know jquery well. kindly need your help

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the fact that you're using DataTables. You want to [add a class conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23382907/laravel-blade-add-a-class-if-a-condition-is-met): `if ( $attandances->total_hours < 9 )`, add a class name to that `<td>` which is styled to be red.

HTML:

```
<td class="{{ ( $attandances->total_hours < 9 ) ? 'danger' : '' }}">
    {{$attandances->total_hours}}
</td>
```

CSS:

```
.danger {
  color: red;
}
```